# Postgres / TypeORM - multiple joins. How should I format the query?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am building a backend microservice which uses postgres as DB and TypeORM (NodeJs) library to manage connections with it.

Imagine that my db contains 3 tables / entities.

1. User table (primary column is - id)
2. Profile table (primary column id, then foreign key user_id pointing to user tables id column)
   There might be multiple profile rows linked to one user
3. Experience table (primary column id, then foreign key profile_id column pointing to profile table id column)
   There might be multiple experience rows linked to one profile

a) Can I perform one complex query to get profile row & all experience rows linked to it?

```
  getFullProfile(profileId: number) {
    return this.profileEntityRepository.createQueryBuilder('profile')
      .where('profile.id = :profileId', { profileId })
      .innerJoinAndMapMany('profile.experience', ExperienceEntity, 'experience', 'experience.id = profile.id')
      .getOne();
  }
```

Sadly this does not return any results (it does if I comment out innerJoinAndMapMany line).

Any suggestions? It doesn't have to be TypeORM api based answer, simple plain query would be sufficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved it.

I changed the typeORM query to this:

```
  getFullProfile(profileId: number) {
    return this.profileEntityRepository.createQueryBuilder('profile')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('profile.experiences', 'experience')
      .where('profile.id = :profileId', { profileId })
      .getOne();
  }
```

To have this working I also needed to add OneToMany column in profile entity which looks like this:

```
  @OneToMany(type => ExperienceEntity, experience => experience.profile)
  experiences: ExperienceEntity[];
```

This doesn't create a column 'experiences' in the table, but is rather needed for TypeORM to understand the situation.